# Is this according to the MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I had a talk with my colleague today on how to properly implement the MVVM pattern.
I came across the following situation for a page:

1. The page displays a form which the user can submit (the primary goal of the page is this form)
2. Besides the form there is a image in the top right corner which the user can click on to display menu options
3. This image and the menu that will display is programmed as follows:
4. The image is defined on the View where tapping the image is DataBound to a command
5. The ViewModel defines the logic of this command
6. This logic will instantiate a new class
7. This class instantiates a specific ContentView that represents a popup
8. The popup gets pushed onto the stack to be displayed to the user

My question now is: Does this violate the MVVM pattern?

I've been reading the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) about the MVVM pattern to find out if this violates the MVVM pattern and my personal opinion is that this architecture violates the pattern.
My reasoning for this is that the ViewModel in this case directly references a ContentView which is exactly the opposite of how it should be according to the pattern, because the ContentView can be seen as the View.
My fix for this architecture would be for the ViewModel to give a signal once the ContentView should be opened and for the View to react to this signal by opening the ContentView itself. In this way you keep the separation between the ViewModel and the View and you keep the View responsible for displaying elements in the UI.

The opinion of my colleague is that this doesn't violate the MVVM pattern because the UI element in question (the popup) is an element foreign to the current view. If it was an element known to the current view (e.g. an element that is part of the form) then the ViewModel has no business in how it's being presented.

But because this is a foreign element that get's instantiated, the current view has and should not have any known on how the new element is being shown. Even to the new element this is limited to exposing/giving the data that needs to be shown (popupTitle, popupContent), but has no regards on how it's actually being shown, since that's the task of the 'new' View.

So the question at the heart of this is: Should the ViewModel declare the specific (Content)View that should be displayed after it checks for logic to be true or false? Or should the specific (Content)View that should be displayed, be referenced by the View instead of the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague is wrong. The foreignness of the UI element is not relevant.

To strictly follow MVVM, the VM classes contain NO REFERENCES TO ANY UI CLASS. Period.

Instead, a VM class manipulates **MODEL** objects *representing* the desired UI. These are passed (perhaps via a Binding) to a View class, which is responsible for converting each Model to UI element(s).

---

*Advanced - Opinion - Controversial*

Sometimes a difficult situation can be resolved by making an `Interface` that exposes non-UI properties of a View class.

A View class could implement that interface, and a VM class could "know" that interface. This allows a View object to be passed around among VM's, without violating the strict division.

It also maintains **testability**, because a "mock" object (that implements that interface) can be substituted in place of that View object.

But the *creation* of the View objects still has to be done in a "hands off" way, perhaps via a "Factory". So VM class never refers to any UI class.

HOWEVER: Nothing you've mentioned should need something advanced like this. Create and manipulate **MODELS**; leave it to UI classes to create UI elements.